# Unable to attach new database

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to attach a database to my SQL Server 2016. I'm getting the following error - any advice?

> Failed to retrieve data for this request.
> (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc)
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>
> C:\TransportTest.bak is not a primary database file. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 5171)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to add a .bak file, .bak files need to be restored and not attached.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A backup(.bak) file is not supposed to be **ATTACHED**. It's a backup file (not .mdf file) that you have to **RESTORE**.

```
RESTORE DATABASE [TransportTest] FROM DISK ='C:\TransportTest.bak'
```

Also you can use try some alternative as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67871507/2118383), in case of issue with .mdf files

Answer (score -1):

You should attach database file with .mdf extension.

> SQL Server database has two operating system files: a data file and a log file.
> Data files contain data and objects such as tables, indexes, stored procedures, and views.
> Every database has one primary data file. The recommended file name extension for primary data files is .mdf

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-files-and-filegroups?view=sql-server-ver15